I created private service access for Cloud SQL using Terraform, but the routes are not being established when I use a self-defined address,
When I created private service access using this code, the VPC` successfully created routes to the private service connection, allowing for a connection to Cloud SQL
resource "google_compute_global_address" "service_range" {
  name          = "${var.prefix}-${var.psc_name}"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  network       = module.carbon-network.network_id
  prefix_length = 20
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_service_connection" {
  network                 = module.carbon-network.network_id
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.service_range.name]
  depends_on              = [google_compute_global_address.service_range]
}

However, when I use a self-defined address, I am unable to connect to Cloud SQL because the routes are not being established
resource "google_compute_global_address" "service_range" {
  name          = "${var.prefix}-${`var.psc`_name}"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  network       = module.carbon-network.network_id
  address = "<private range>"
  prefix_length = 20`your text`
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_service_connection" {
  network                 = module.carbon-network.network_id
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.service_range.name]
  depends_on              = [google_compute_global_address.service_range]
}

enter image description here
these custom route don't shows when use self defined address `
